# Is there an alternative to url_for for CherryPy?

Tags: python, flask, cherrypy

Flask has a url_for method call, to set up urls from its global settings folder.

How do I manage something similar to that with CherryPy?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

You can access the mounted url handlers through

```
cherrypy.tree.apps[mount_point].root
```

root is always the mounted instance to the mount point. So a reverse function would look like:

```
def reverse(cls):
    # get link to a class type
    for app_url in cherrypy.tree.apps.keys():
        if isinstance(cherrypy.tree.apps[app_url].root, cls):
            # NOTE: it will return with the first mount point of this class
            return app_url
```

[how to get url of an object in cherrypy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755471/how-to-get-url-of-an-object-in-cherrypy)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you use [routes dispatcher](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/concepts/dispatching.html#other-dispatchers), you have its url_for.